# properties in c# not showing correct result

Tags: c#

i am a newbie to c#.
i was reading about properties.
i have coded this and i think the result should be displayed "Value to big" but it's not showing anything.
please tell me where am i wrong.
thanks.

```
       private int _age;

        public int Age
        {
            get { return _age; }
            set
            {
                if (value < 10)
                {
                    Age = value;
                    Console.WriteLine("Value to Small");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Value to Big");
                }
            }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var banmeet = new Program();
            banmeet._age = 22;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read about private backing fields and public properties [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `Age` instead of `_age`. `_age` is simply a private member, where as `Age` is the property you are wanting to set.

```
banmeet.Age = 22;
```

Also as Tim Jarvis pointed out, inside of the age setter, you need to set the age to `_age`.

```
if (value < 10)
{
    _age = value;
    Console.WriteLine("Value to Small");
}
```

You can read more about properties vs fields [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/295109/724591).

Comment: plus, in the setter, you should set _age = value (not Age)

Comment: Thanks but please correct me if i am  wrong but aren't the values going inside the private variable or they are set in property?

Comment: When you create a new object, `var banmeet = new Class();`, you won't have access to `_age` since it's private. When you create the `Age` property, you have to return and set the `_age` variable, since `Age` itself doesn't contain a value.

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistakes. First you want use this code:

```
    private int _age;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            if (_age < 10)
            {
                _age = value;
                Console.WriteLine("Value to Small");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Value to Big");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var banmeet = new Program();
        banmeet.Age = 22;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Then if use above code output is *Value to Small* because _age is 0.

For the correct result you should use this:

```
   private int _age;

        public int Age
        {
            get { return _age; }
            set
            {
                _age = value;

                Console.WriteLine(_age < 10 ? "Value to Small" : "Value to Big");
            }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var banmeet = new Program();
            banmeet.Age = 22;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting _age, which is a field, not a property.  So your property setter won't be called.

Also, you shouldn't set Age in your property setter, you should set _age.  Setting Age will result in infinite recursion (and ultimately a stack overflow) since the setter is invoking itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Encapsulation** is defined 'as the process of enclosing one or more items within a physical or logical package'. Encapsulation, in object oriented programming methodology, prevents access to implementation details. Better to set the value for `_age` instead of Age .

```
    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 10)
            {
                _age = value;
                Console.WriteLine("Value to Small");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Value to Big");
            }
        }
    }
```